# student t confidence interval in python

Tags: python, numpy, distribution

I am interested in using python to compute a confidence interval from a student t.

I am using the StudentTCI() function in Mathematica and now need to code the same function in python http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/HypothesisTesting/ref/StudentTCI.html

I am not quite sure how to build this function myself, but before I embark on that, is this function in python somewhere? Like numpy? (I haven't used numpy and my advisor advised not using numpy if possible).

What would be the easiest way to solve this problem? Can I copy the source code from the StudentTCI() in numpy (if it exists) into my code as a function definition?

edit: I'm going to need to build the Student TCI using python code (if possible). Installing scipy has turned into a dead end. I am having the same problem everyone else is having, and there is no way I can require Scipy for the code I distribute if it takes this long to set up.

Anyone know how to look at the source code for the algorithm in the scipy version? I'm thinking I'll refactor it into a python definition.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I guess you could use [scipy.stats.t](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.t.html) and its `interval` method:

```
In [1]: from scipy.stats import t
In [2]: t.interval(0.95, 10, loc=1, scale=2)  # 95% confidence interval
Out[2]: (-3.4562777039298762, 5.4562777039298762)
In [3]: t.interval(0.99, 10, loc=1, scale=2)  # 99% confidence interval
Out[3]: (-5.338545334351676, 7.338545334351676)
```

Sure, you can make your own function if you like. Let's make it look like in `Mathematica`:

```
from scipy.stats import t


def StudentTCI(loc, scale, df, alpha=0.95):
    return t.interval(alpha, df, loc, scale)

print StudentTCI(1, 2, 10)
print StudentTCI(1, 2, 10, 0.99)
```

Result:

```
(-3.4562777039298762, 5.4562777039298762)
(-5.338545334351676, 7.338545334351676)
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I need. I am trying to install scipy (win7 64x), and it is not as straightforward as it should be?? I am using 32 bit python so I believe I want the 32 bit scipy as well, but I'm not sure how to get it. I'm installing a thing called anaconda right now which I guess should get the job done? There's not any way to just install scipy I take it?

Comment: Anaconda is done, and it didn't install scipy. line 29, in <module>
    from scipy.stats import t
ImportError: No module named scipy.stats

Comment: @SwimBikeRun, I suggest you install [Enthought Canopy](https://www.enthought.com/products/canopy/). It provides an easy and straightforward way to install and manage python packages. Scipy is included in the Express version, so you don't have to pay for it. There's also [pythonxy](https://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/) which comes with scipy as well, but I never really used it.

Comment: Just for future users, I spent way too much time installing virtual box + linux, and several dual boot linuxes (ubuntu, mint) and now I am back in windows 7 64 bit but with running everything as 32 bit tools. Things are working great now.

Comment: Where do you get the documentation for the t.interval function? I can't figure out what the loc and scale do from this - http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.t.html?highlight=stats.t#scipy.stats.t

Comment: @SwimBikeRun, loc is a location parameter or the mean value μ. Scale in this case is variance σ. If you don't want to use `SciPy`, you can find the source code for the distribution and it's methods [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/stats/distributions.py). `SciPy` however relies on `NumPy`, therefore your users will have to install it.

Comment: Ah I see. I am trying to copy over the source code so my users won't have to install it. So on line 488,489, I see     def interval(self, alpha):
        return self.dist.interval(alpha, *self.args, **self.kwds). Then I can't find where this dist.inverval is defined. Where would that be located

Comment: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.13.3/scipy/stats/distributions.py#L788-L819

Comment: The value it returns is the two tailed test. Is it possible to get the one tailed test? For example here to get the one-tailed test of 0.95 and degree 10?